# How to set window scroll top based on slider percentage

Tags: jquery, html, uislider, uiwindow

I have a slider and I would like to make it set the scroll top percentage of the window to whatever the the slider percentage is, currently however I cant seem to get the right equation to make this work, I also notice my slider isnt very smooth, and jumps from one end to another without stopping where my slider leaves off, what would be the best way to fix these two issues? any help will go a long way thanks, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edmundoto/jg84x36u/) showing the issue

```
$('.bar-long').slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {

    //This equation should make the window the same percentage as the slider but not working    
      $(window).scrollTop(((100 - ui.value)* $(window).height())/100);  

    }
});
```

Comment: Take the percentege of the slider, then take the whole height of the window and then multiply the percentage with the height ( eg. 0.8 * 1200 ) and then set the scroll to this pixel. I think this will work

Comment: shouldn't the document height be somewhere in the equation?

Comment: Would you be able to make an example equation with the document height?

Answer (score 1):

The right equation is :

```
$(window).scrollTop((100 - ui.value)/100 * $(document).height())
```

To make it smooth, you will have to place the scrollbar outside of the scrolled container (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwzxzasz/1/)) but at least in my version of this approach you need an `overflow: hidden` on the content container, which removes not only the browser scrollbar but also the mouse wheel functionality.
If you have a seperate content container like this, you will have to use its height instead of the document height because latter will only be the window height.